# How do I print or export a TwinCat class diagram (UML diagram)?

Tags: twincat

I'm looking for a way to print or export a class diagram (UML diagram) from the TwinCat XAE environment.  Is there any way to export to PDF? At the moment, the only solution I have is to screenshot parts of the diagram and paste them into another document.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a simple solution to my problem.  All you have to do is right click on the class diagram in the Solution Explorer.  In the menu, you will see an option to "Create Picture".  Once you have done this, just follow the instructions on the dialogue box.  Once the .bmp file is created, you can print it to PDF.

[image: Right click on the Class Diagram]